# Simulate time series with periodic spikes

Tags: time-series, simulation, seasonality

I have multiple time series representing a process that operates in batches. It consists of many small intervals interleaved by periodic long intervals (spikes) at the offset of each batch. The period between the spikes varies slightly.

Without knowing the period between spikes (i.e., the spikes are unlabeled), is there a way to learn it from data and simulate a time series with similar properties?

## What I tried

Autocorrelation learns/simulates this process poorly because the lagged correlations are applied to *all* points, also the non-spike points, resulting in non-spikey simulated values. I tried e.g. `forecast::auto.arima()`. Bootstrapping naturally doesn't respect the temporal structure out-of-the-box.

## Data

Here's some data that approximately represents the kind of intervals I'm working with, having spikes every 9-11 intervals (it could be 18-22 for another process and the spike height could be different, etc.).

The spike-intervals are superimposed on (shifted) log-normal data. I.e., there's a true minimum interval (maximum speed) and then a fat tail of variability.

```r
N = 100

# The periodic spikes
periodic_intervals = rep(0, N)
periodic_intervals[cumsum(sample(9:11, 10^3, replace = TRUE))] = 1
periodic_intervals = periodic_intervals[1:N] * runif(N, 100, 150)

# For all data
lognormal_intervals = 20 + exp(rnorm(N, 2, 1))

# Superimpose the two
intervals = lognormal_intervals + periodic_intervals
```

```
plot(intervals[1:50], type = "b")
```

[image]

Comment: The pattern in the graph looks quite regular. One simple solution would be to add dummy variables to the model which capture that regularity.

Comment: @MikeHunter I would love it if you could expand since I'm, out of ideas. In the above, the spikes occur with intervals of 9-11 samples. I've tried threshold solutions (raw threshold; upper quantile, kmeans with k=2) but they become very fragile when the spikes are less clear and/or when the period is short, e.g., every 4-5 samples. It still seems like the best solution, but I wanted to see if there was a more principled/information-using solution.

Comment: Ok...so add 0,1 dummy variables to the model which are equal to 1 when the spikes are observed and zero elsewhere, a very simple heuristic. If this is unclear, add a snippet of raw data to help clarify how it might work as the code provided isn't illustrative.

Comment: What assumptions are you willing to make about the non spiked data?

Comment: @DemetriPananos I updated the question to explain that spikes (who have temporal structure) are superimposed on draws from a shifted log-normal (i.e., no temporal structure).

Comment: @MikeHunter I updated the question with the fact that the spikes are unlabeled. In many cases, the in-between-spikes-data generate intervals longer than the spikes, so a simple threshold model cannot be used to label the spikes.

Comment: I'm no expert in time series analysis, but is it possible to learn the spikes with an STL-decomposition? [Here's](https://feasts.tidyverts.org/) a vignette using the [tidyverts](https://tidyverts.org) framework. Maybe this is useful.